# Import Angular 2 project to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, typescript, import, visual-studio-2017, webstorm

I have project made with Angular 2 framework in WebStorm.

I have been looking for a simple explanation for how to open and work on it in Visual Studio 2017.

Any reference will be good.

Comment: File -> Open -> Project

Comment: I have try that and it does not work like that.

Answer (score 2):

With Visual Studio 2015, you can open your Angular app like this :

**File > Open > Web Site > File System > Select your app folder**